# how to use openworkspaceaction in the start() method of my Application

Tags: java, rcp

I want to implement the same workspace launcher in RCP project as before eclipse started,please help me.

I built a new RCP project

Answer (score 0):

The 'choose workspace' dialog is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.ChooseWorkspaceDialog`. Since this is an internal class it is not part of the Eclipse API and you should not try to use it.

If you want your RCP to use a workspace it would be best to use the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` application, since there is a lot of initialization that has to be done.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. What should I do if I want to realize the workspace launcher pop-up window before the RCP project starts?